# Calculating angular momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

A particle of mass $m$ is at a very large distance $p$ from origin $O$ and is moving with velocity $\vec{V}$ which is perpendicular to $\vec{OP}$. I have to calculate angular momentum $L$ of the particle.

I know that $\vec{L}=\vec{r}\times m\vec{\dot r}$.
Since $|\vec{r}|=p$ and $|\dot r|=V$ and $\alpha=90^{\circ}$ is angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{\dot r}$, I got that $L=|\vec{r}||m\vec{\dot r}|sin\alpha=pmV\cdot 1=pmV$.

In the book, it's written that $L=pV$. What happened with mass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your book is incorrect. Since $p$ is a length, $pV$ and $L$ cannot be equal by dimensional analysis alone.

The *specific* angular momentum, however, does equal $pV$, though it is very misleading to use the letter $L$ for it. A body's specific angular momentum is its angular momentum divided by its mass, i.e. its angular momentum per unit mass. It captures the interesting *kinematics* of angular momentum (i.e. how bodies move in space through time) but it is quite useless when it comes to *dynamics* (i.e. how bodies interact).

Comment: so it's correct what I wrote? It's written so through the whole book without any explanation about mass. The same for potential and kinetic energy.

Comment: You are correct, maybe your book calls it specific angular momentum, since that is equal to the equation from your book.

Comment: @fibonatic yes, exactly. It's written specific, I didn't know that this term exists (I am not physics student). Thanks.